# How to prevent concurrent access in MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC controller accessible at a specific URL, which when called, runs a series of time consuming process (post-processing data from a db).

I need to make sure that when the method is being called by an User, the process start once. If any other Users access that specific URL when the post-processing is running  no simultaneously post-processing occurs.

My questions:

- Should I use [locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8544e2s.aspx) in C#?
- Should I use some like inProgress flag in DB, so I can mark when the processing start and end?
- Any other solutions?

Comment: "Thread safe" and "blocks concurrent access automagically" aren't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: Of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to scale to multiple machines, an in memory lock is not an option, but a lock in the database is probably the simplest.

For example, you could create a lock table with a unique id field. When you get a request, try to insert a row with id 1. If you succeed, postprocess and delete the key.

Any other request that tries to insert the key while they key exists during another run will fail the insert and not run the job.

Comment: This is by far the easiest way I have seen for making sure only one process is running at any one time within a web application and I have looked all over for different ways of providing a single job running process.

Answer (score 3):

Each concurrent request will have its own thread.

It's the set of in-progress tasks you need to make thread safe. This resource will be a shared, so multiple web requests will try to access at the same time.

There are concurrent collections in .Net 4.0 onwards, which make your life easier. What you need is a concurrent set, however no such class exists. You can use ConcurrentDictionary instead, using just the keys for your request IDs.

This assumes you have only one web server, otherwise you will need a database or shared service solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, do you think LOCKS could be used effectively  also in my case?

Comment: @GibboK yes, but it will be easier to introduce a performance issue or a deadlock, so I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: Thanks James for your advice. I believe it depends on now may hits simultaneous the controller receives. My controller won't be "public available" in my specific case I expect fews concurrent requests, App is running only on a single server.

Comment: "Each concurrent request will have its own thread." - somewhat wrong -  each request handled by unique instance of controller(s) that lease avaialble threads while actually executing code, this is especially true to modern (MVC4+) code with async controllers where multiple concurrent requests may endup running on the same thread while other one is "await'ing".

Comment: @GibboK - be very careful with locking - normally you should be using `lock` around quick predictable operations, not slow once with almost unbounded execution (like network or DB access) .

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what do you think about "lock in db" solution?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if a request is awaiting, it's not concurrent with the other running requests

Comment: @GibboK Lock in db is probably more appropriate in your case (as suggested by Joachim Isaksson's answer) - you want to mark "this chunk of work is already worked on" - so store that information where the rest of data related to "work" is. I.e. in case of in-memory structures `lock` is often good solution, with external data (especially with potential of being used by multiple processes) in-process state likely is not appropriate.

Comment: @JamesL yes... depending on definition - from user's point of view if server accepted 2 requests they are "concurrent requests", clearly from code "thread safety/parallel execution" they are not "concurrently processesed by CPU".

Answer (score 2):

To be more exact: They are thread safe becuase the controller is created NEW for every request. 2 requests do not share one controller.

Comment: +1. Answers title of the post. Even more exact - Controller's methods/instance data not "thread safe" in common meaning of it (as in "ok to be accessed from any thread at any time"), but rather don't have issues with thread safety themself. Note that body of question talks about complete different issue (make sure particular request runs only one instance).